# Image resize,crop with gd afresh every time or caching?

Tags: php, image, gd

I found [this really nice function](http://joedesigns.com/v22/index.php?page=scripts_widgets&id=67) that receives your desired proportions and resizes/crops the image for you. The function requires ImageMagick to work.

Will it be better to cache the image or resize it every time? I'm pretty sure using gd will be slower than caching, but it won't require me to use ImageMagick, and I still haven't successfully tweaked it (something with ImageMagicks' convert won't work).

Comment: For caching wouldn't you need to generate the image the first time anyway (still requiring ImageMagick)? Or do you mean generating all the images with a separate program and then using them?

Comment: I have an image, i want to resize it. I'm asking whether it will be significantly slower in your opinion to just crop/resize the image every time OR resize it once, cache and hope for the best?

Comment: It depends on how many hits you'd get for that same image...

Comment: If I have just a few or a ton, how does it matter?

Comment: It matters to understand what "better" means for you. The image will certainly be served faster if it's cached, but whether it's worth for you to spend time implementing a cache or not that depends on how busy your site is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Image generation functions are very expensive.  Caching will almost always be significantly faster, and isn't that hard to implement.  Come up with a quick naming scheme that will take into account the size of the image ('userid-123-200x400.jpg') and uniquely identify it, and when time comes to serve it, just check if it's there and generate it and save it into a cache directory if necessary.

Disk space is cheaper than CPU and scales much better, and your page load times will thank you for it.